# Is there a well-known secular sentence that uses all three of the imperative, indicative, and subjunctive moods?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, latin, subordinate-clauses, imperatives, indicative

The following English sentence, a 19ᵗʰtranslation from [a medieval Latin hymn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_come,_O_come,_Emmanuel#Latin_Text) from the 12ᵗʰ or 13ᵗʰ century, is well known, at least [among Christians](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/activities/view.cfm?id=560):

> O come O come Emmanuel,
>   And ransom captive Israel,
>   That mourns in lonely exile here
>   Until the Son of God appear.

It uses the imperative mood (*come, come, ransom*), the indicative mood (*mourns*) and the subjunctive mood (*appear*).

This sentence uses three moods, but it also packs in a good deal of Christian theology, which makes it problematic in an English class, so is there a well-known secular sentence that uses all three of the imperative, indicative, and subjunctive moods?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45247/discussion-on-question-by-airymouse-is-there-a-well-known-secular-sentence-that).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't indicate what purpose this thread will have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, subjunctive mood is a bit opaque to me, and it's more than one sentence, but perhaps

> Just sit right back
>
> And you'll hear a tale
>
> A tale of a fateful trip,
>
> That started from this tropic port,
>
> Aboard this tiny ship.
>
> ...
>
> The weather started getting rough,
>
> The tiny ship was tossed;
>
> If not for the courage of the fearless crew
>
> The Minnow would be lost.
>
> (The Minnow would be lost.)

"Just sit right back" sounds like imperative to me, and I *think* "If not for the courage of the fearless crew, the Minnow would be lost" matches some of the [examples I've found of subjunctive mood](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/), with everything else in indicative.

Comment: “The Minnow would be lost” is not subjunctive; it’s a conditional construction. In the examples on the Grammarist page, the subjunctive is in the subordinate clause (“if X _were_”), not in the main clause with _would_. Had your excerpt read “If it were not for the courage…”, that would have been a subjunctive.

Answer (score 0):

> "Star night, Star bright.
>   First Star I've seen tonight,
>   Wish I may, wish I might
>   Have the wish I wish to-night"

*First Star* is invoked to "**wish**" (imperative) something for me.
What that is is in the subjunctive, "that I **may have**, that I **might have..."**
"the wish **I wish** tonight" is in the indicative.

This [anthology](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/46976) gives a different version which is parsed differently.

'Subjunctives' (meaning *may* clauses that require subjunctive in Latin) survive in a few granny quotes, such as "I would'n if I were you!"
and in a few incantations.

Comment: Not how I learned it or interpret it.  https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/46976

Comment: Well that's Dorling-K for you. Like British-Heritage it simplifies and emasculates. Lectio difficilior melius,